# form element inside a modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I tried putting my login form inside a modal and added data-dismiss="modal" to the submit button. The modal is dismissed successfully but the POST method does not seem to "fire" and the page remains the same. Anyone else tried putting a form inside a modal and got it working?

```
     <div class="modal hide fade" id="signin-register" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="image-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">


    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">

            <div class="span6">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">

                        <legend>Sign in</legend>

                        <form class="navbar-form pull-right" method="POST" action="login/">
                          <input type="hidden" name="a" value="validate" />
                            <input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                            <input class="input-small" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                            <button class="btn btn-small btn-info" type="submit" class="btn2" data-dismiss="modal"><strong>sign in</strong></button>
                        </form>

                        <legend>Register</legend>


                        <form action="" method="POST" id="register_form">

                            <label>Username:*</label><input class="input-small" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />

                            <label>Password:*</label><input class="input-small" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />

                            <label>Email:*</label><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" /><br>
                            <input type="submit" name="a" value="Register" data-dismiss="modal"/>

                         </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="span6">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I double confirmed that the login form works outside the modal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning `data-dismiss` to a link or button will intercept the click event of that button and prevent it from bubbling up. If you put `data-dismiss` on a form submit button, the actual "submit" action will never be fired and the form will not be submitted.

If you're going to submit the form via AJAX, have the success event trigger the dismissal of the form. If you're doing a traditional form post, don't worry about dismissing the modal since the page will reload or redirect.

Comment: Thank you all for taking your time to answer. Worked after removing the  data attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Elements with `data-dismiss="modal"` are supposed to be for dismissing the modal, any default behavior  (like submitting a form) will be overridden.

If you need to submit a form, do not use this attribute on the submit button. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite easy. You don't need the data-dismiss attribute on the submit. I'm using MVC4, and do this routinely:

```
<div id="mdlProceed" class="modal hide fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         Body
        </div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null,
                               new { area = "MyArea", controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" }, FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" accesskey="c" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel" alt="Return" />
                <input type="submit" name="start" id="start" accesskey="n" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Please Wait..." value="Continue" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried, and it has worked fine!

```
<div style="width:800px"  class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">Some header
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">Some body
    <input...... fields..... >
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">  
       <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitData();">
       <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This misses the point of the question entirely, not sure how it got upvoted. Also, what is this `onclick="SubmitData();"` all about? At the very least it should have `type="submit"`...