# Post back with FormMethod.Post using a modal

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a jQuery Datatable which has some custom buttons, when clicked a boostrap modal is called. The modal asks wether the user wants to deactivate an account.

In my `example2` Datatable I pass the unique identifier (`pid`) of the account to the modal when the button is clicked:

```
    $('#example2').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var oData = oTable.fnGetData(this);
        var pid = oData[0];
        $(".modal-footer #pid").val(pid);
        //alert(pid);
    });
```

The problem I am facing is trying to post back to my controller using the below form method in the modal, how could I make this work:

**Modal:**

```
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Warning!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to deactivate this account?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                @using (@Html.BeginForm("ProviderActivate", "AdminPanel", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="pid" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Publish" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" />
                }
                @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>*@
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment the above modal simply doesnt work. I click the deactivate (`Publish`) button inside the modal and nothing is posted back to the controller no account is deactivated/activated. If I set a break point on the controller action below and click publish, nothing happens. The breakpoint isnt hit.

```
    public ActionResult ProviderActivate(FormCollection form) //change id to form post hidden element refer to TSProps
    {
        if (!CustomSecurity.IsAdmin(User.Identity.Name))
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        string pid = form["pid"];

        bool any = _db.CareProviders.Where(c => c.ProviderId == pid && !c.Activated.HasValue).Any();
        ....etc
```

Comment: What problem are you having? What is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with OP, it was found that having the data-dismiss attribute on the submit button was causing the form not to post.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422842/form-element-inside-a-modal) post explains why this happens.

<s>You can add a hidden field to your form, then assign the ID to the hidden, which would then make it available in your controller action when you post to your controller.</s>

```
<input type="hidden" name="accountId" id="accountId" val="" />
```

Then add another line to your example2 on click function

```
$('#accountId').val(pid);
```

Finally, in your controller, add a parameter to your controller action called accountId.

Comment: Does it matter if its hidden, I have shown it in my example because I wanted to see the number being populated. I dont think it does. Also my Controller is a `FormCollection form`

Comment: No, it doesn't matter, you just have to have that ID in your form once you post. If you have a FormCollection then you won't need to add the parameter

Comment: Yeah so this is exactly what I already have and it doesnt work?

Comment: @GarrithGraham I just read your edit, when you click the Publish button, are you hitting your controller action?

Comment: Break point isnt being hit for the controller action when I click publish?

Comment: Do you have an HttpPost attribute on that action?

Comment: Yes I do, it could be something to do with the modal dimissing after I click publish? Seems like there is no post back. Or possibly because the value of the hidden field is set to "pid".

Comment: Could be. Try removing the data-dismiss attribute from the submit button

Comment: Also inspecting the html I noticed `<input name="pid" id="pid" value="CS2003000137 " type="hidden"> ` there seems to be a space at the end of the value? Could this cause the issue?

Comment: That wouldn't cause a form to not post.

Comment: Looks like it was the data-dismiss causing the issue. Strange.

Comment: I edited my answer with a link to help explain why it happens. Basically the bootstrap dismiss event happens first, and prevents the event from bubbling up, therefore preventing form posting.

Comment: I have noticed tho that the pid is null when I set a break point in the controller now.

Comment: Probably better to post another question for that. But it could be the jquery selector in your javascript. Try changing $('.modal-footer #pid') to just $('#pid')